# Images not replacing with css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

wonder if you can help.

I want to change the social media icons within a plugin to my own.  I don't want to change the plug in source files so that I can continue to update the plugin as updates come in.

I have put this in the custom css box but the images are not replacing.  Any clues why?

```
 #upme-icon-linkedin-sign {
     background-image: url("/wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/linkedin.png");
 }

 #upme-icon-twitter {
     background-image: url("/wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/twitter.png");
 }
```

Here is an example of the page it needs to change on http://tinyurl.com/pcnb3us

The theme is using FontAwesome for the current icons if that helps?

Thanks in advance

I FOUND THE ANSWER - BUT IT SAYS FOR USERS WITH A REP UNDER 10 I CANNOT ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION - SO POSTING HERE INSTEAD!

Found the answer

```
 .upme-icon-linkedin-sign {
     position:relative;
 }    
 .upme-icon-linkedin-sign:before {
         position:absolute;
         content:url(/wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/linkedin.png); 
     }
```

Comment: have you checked that after you assign the css, the plugin assigns it's background image?

Comment: make the path to the image relative to where the css file is and also check that you put this rule after the original rule and make it as specific as any rule you are overriding

Comment: @Haji - not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Pete Yes, tried all variations of the URL nothing seems to work for me.  This is wordpress, so the plug in has its own css file which I cannot mess with because it will affect being able to install future updates. So the css change needs to be put in a custom css file - which handles changes outside of the theme and plugins.

Comment: i think after assign your background image, the css in plug-in assigns it's background image..

Comment: Your icon is on the before: `.upme-icon-twitter:before { content: "\f099"; }`, ps you shouldn't really shhorten your urls as people are less inclined to click on them as they don't know where they will go

Comment: I shorten URLs because I don't want an obvious backlink showing in analytics or this page appearing when people search for the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
#upme-icon-twitter {
   background-image: url("../wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/twitter.png");
}
```

And once check the image path that you have got while inspecting the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#upme-icon-twitter {
 background-image: url("../wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/twitter.png");
}
```

or this:

```
#upme-icon-twitter {
 background-image: url("~/wp-content/plugins/upme/css/images/twitter.png");
}
```

I'm normally pulling the item into the css file, so i get the whole path, and then delete the unnecessary.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue doesn't appear to the an incorrect path.  Tried both the above and the full URLs and nothing changes.